# Oracle Apex "Database Link" - only for Oracle to Oracle or others as well?

Tags: sql-server, oracle-apex

Can I use the "Database Link" tool in Apex to connect to MS SQL Server? Or just other Oracle DBs?

This is what the DBLink creation form looks like in Apex (red star indicates required field):
[image: dblink creation form]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DB Links are for other oracle databases only. Due to your situation (sql server and oracle integration), maybe you should think the other way around: create a linked server on sql server to connect to oracle and create a procedure there to send the data to oracle.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this form is designed only for Oracle connections:

- SQL Server (and other RDBMSs?) has no concept of a SID or "service name", but one is required here
- [The documentation](http://www.oracle.com/pls/apx41/master_index) does not refer to other database platforms
- The [generic database link documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/statements_5005.htm) says that Oracle Heterogeneous Services are required to use non-Oracle systems in a database link, but OHS is not mentioned in the Apex documentation at all

Comment: So the tool/form does not allow it - but if @antonpug wishes, he could still run an sql command which has the required parameterisation (it's just that the question does not specify this). The link would then even appear in the database link list in apex, just with an inadequate amount of details (probably).